# Ending a word in a stressed "h"

Tags: pronunciation, phonotactics, conlang

I am a native English speaker, and as far as I know, my language has no words that end in a stressed h sound. So, I'm creating a conlang, and I thought about putting one at the end of a word, but I have no clue how to pronounce it without a vowel following it (in other words, not "ha", just "h"). Any advice?
PS: In case it helps, this h would follow the IPA sound ӡ.

Comment: You need to learn phonetics before you can make a good conlang. Catford's _Practical Introduction to Phonetics_ repays detailed study.

Answer (score 4):

"Stress" is a property of syllables, not consonants, so you could drop the restriction "stressed". In fact, no words in English end in [h], leaving out spelling where it is an orthographic device to indicate something else. There are some languages with final *h* (Sundanese, Arabic, Somali and North Saami in one interpretation), but it isn't common across languages. Having words like [mæʒh] would be particularly challenging to pronounce, and if final [h] appeared *only* after [ʒ] then that smacks of misanalysis (like, why not just say it's a pronunciation feature of final /ʒ/?).

Arabic being a relatively widely-taught language, it might be best to "get the hang" of final *h* by practicing it in Arabic, and then transfer the skills to the conlang. The downside is that online teaching materials usually require you to read the script. Perhaps fdb knows of a pedagogical list of online final-h words with recordings.

Answer (score 1):

A typical approach to pronouncing final consonants is adding a short [Schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) `[ə]` after it and then practicing with gradual shortening the vowel to the minimal possible length.

I have no academic books on this topic, but I have personal experience teaching my Thai friends how to pronounce English final consonants. In Thai language, a considerable amount of consonant sounds can't be final in the syllable, so average people have difficulty even with seemingly easy final `[l]`, `[s]`, or even voiced plosives `[b/d/g]` — while, obviously, having no problem with these consonants as initial ones in the syllable.
This technique has helped me a lot.